# MySQL sort by two columns of one table

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id INT, for_id INT, comms VARCHAR(50));
    INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,0, 'boo'),
                                    (2,1, 'John'),
                                    (3,0, 'Zoe'),
                                    (4,3, 'bar'),
                                    (5,1, 'Don'),
                                    (6,3, 'FOO'),
                                    (7,1, 'Doe');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859933/6

How can I get next:

```
1.0.'boo'
2.1.'John'
5.1.'Don'
7.1.'Doe'
3.0.'Zoe'
4.3.'bar'
6.3.'FOO'
```

Thanks!

Comment: use order by Id. Is that you want?

Comment: columns not ordered in `id asc, for_id asc`, he doesn't need that, He also doesn't clarify the question.

Comment: what's the real order you want ?

Comment: @wajeeh Yes that's what I was asking him

Comment: updated my answer. Please check

Comment: [Please look here!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859933/6)

Comment: By just looking to that same fiddle how can we understand what you want.Can you explain clearly what exactly you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is what you exactly want or not, you should do some explanation for the result order in post.

```
select *
from table_name
order by 
    case when for_id = 0 then concat(id, for_id) + 0
         else concat(for_id, id) + 0
    end
```

and [**SQLFiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859933/25).

***Updated:***

Try following again,

```
select *
from table_name
order by 
    case when for_id = 0 then mod(concat(for_id, id) + 0, 10)
         else mod(concat(id, for_id) + 0, 10)
    end
    , id asc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf4c8/10)

***Updated again:***

```
select *
from table_name
order by 
    case when for_id = 0 then id
         else for_id
    end
    , id asc
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/365539/25)

Comment: Thank you, but if I add a record to the table, the query does not work properly.

Comment: @ChooHwan For the additional record, what is your desired result?

Comment: ...8.1, 13.1, 3.0, 4.3, 6.3, 10.3, 12.3 9.0, 11.9 [Not here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf4c8/1)

Comment: I'm sorry (no more tears :) but please see after "id"=14 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/365539/1

Comment: @Forward Good one!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `order by` , it can get more than one column

```
Select * from table_name 
  order by id asc, for_id asc;
```

Comment: if you look at the sqlfiddle in the question, You will see that your answer the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Use order by and Cancat

```
select Concat(id,'.',for_id) as id ,comms
from table_name
order by id asc,for_id asc
```

**Updated :**

Use order by and apply `case` statement as per your condition

```
select *
from table_name
order by 
    case when for_id = 0 then concat(id, for_id) + 1
         else concat(for_id, id) + 0
    end
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/859933/25

Comment: @ChooHwan did you got the answer you're looking for? If so you can accept the answer

Comment: No. Please look at my question.

Comment: @ChooHwan just by looking to that same fiddle how can we understand what you want.Can you explain clearly in words what exactly you need?

Comment: Thank you.
If 'for_id' == 0 - this is "category", else - "subcategory"
I need to get a list of categories, followed by their sub categories.

Comment: 1.0.'boo'
2.1.'John'
5.1.'Don'
7.1.'Doe'
3.0.'Zoe'
4.3.'bar'
6.3.'FOO'

Comment: oh use case conditions then

Comment: @ChooHwan Thanks understood now it clearly..updated the answer now..use case statement for it

Comment: No sir... Thank you, but if I add a record to the table, the query does not work properly. [Please see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf4c8/1)

Comment: @ChooHwan just try with multiple cases.

Comment: @Forward Hey Yes I copied it once but Check my fiddles too. The OP was not clear with his question and I updated my answer for 4times. anyway I am just trying to help him.

Comment: Best regards, Shivkumar!